# QT Custom QStyle for QTabBar and QIcon

Tags: qt, styles, qtabbar, qicon

I have customize a Qtabbar's QMdiarea to get horizontal tab instead of vertical tab like this :
http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Customizing_QTabWidget%27s_QTabBar

But i want to insert icon in my QTabBar.
If I apply my custom style to my QTabBar my icons doesn't appear.
If I don't apply, my icon appear.

here my custom style :

```
class CustomTabStyle : public QPlastiqueStyle
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
QSize sizeFromContents(ContentsType type, const QStyleOption *option,const QSize &size, const QWidget *widget) const
{
    QSize s = QPlastiqueStyle::sizeFromContents(type, option, size, widget);
    if (type == QStyle::CT_TabBarTab)
        s.transpose();
    return s;
}
void drawControl(ControlElement element, const QStyleOption *option, QPainter *painter, const QWidget *widget) const
{
    if (element == CE_TabBarTabLabel)
    {
        if (const QStyleOptionTab *tab = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionTab *>(option))
        {
            QStyleOptionTab opt(*tab);
            opt.shape = QTabBar::RoundedNorth;
            QPlastiqueStyle::drawControl(element, &opt, painter, widget);
            return;
        }
    }
    QPlastiqueStyle::drawControl(element, option, painter, widget);
}
```

};

and i apply my style like this :

```
    mMdiAreaDock=aMdiArea;
m_pMdiAreaTabBar = NULL;
QObjectList listChildren = mMdiAreaDock->children();
for (QObjectList::Iterator i = listChildren.begin(); i != listChildren.end(); ++i)
{
    if (QString((*i)->metaObject()->className()) == "QTabBar")
    {
        m_pMdiAreaTabBar = dynamic_cast<QTabBar*>(*i);
        break;
    }
}
m_pMdiAreaTabBar->setStyle(new CustomTabStyle());
return 0;
```

where mMdiAreaDock is an QMdiArea
and m_pMdiAreaTabBar is a QTabBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
const QStyleOptionTab *tab = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionTab *>(option));
QStyleOptionTab opt(*tab);
```

`option` is an instance of `QStyleOptionTabV2`.

When you create a new object `QStyleOptionTab opt` with copy constructor, you lose some important data which extended `QStyleOptionTabV2` contains including information about an icon.

Use this code instead:

```
if (const QStyleOptionTabV2 *tab = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionTabV2 *>(option))
{
    QStyleOptionTabV2 opt(*tab);
    opt.shape = QTabBar::RoundedNorth;
    QPlastiqueStyle::drawControl(element, &opt, painter, widget);
    return;
}
```

ps. I used this code to assign an icon for a specific tab:

```
 m_pMdiAreaTabBar->setTabIcon(0, icon);
```